# How do you enable pass-through of USB/ethernet on a Dell docking station? (WD19TB)

Tags: thunderbolt, docking-station

I have a laptop docked to a [WD19TB](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-wd19tb-dock/drivers) via Thunderbolt but USB and RJ45 connections to the dock aren't visible to the laptop.

How do you configure the dock to allow these devices?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195666/dell-wd19tb-thunderbolt-dock-failed-to-authorize-device/1196574#1196574

Answer (score 0):

Open Notifications area (bottom right) and resolve:

[image: bloody stupid notification]

If that does not work, disable the need for approval:

- Hold F2/Del and boot to UEFI settings
- Under `Thunderbolt Security Level` change the selection to `No Security`

Comment: I have the exact same issue with the Dell WD19TB Connected to a 16" MacBook Pro 2021 running MacOS Sonoma. No LAN is being picked up. @RJFalconer Are you able to expand your answer for Mac also?

Comment: Sorry, no. Changing settings in the UEFI will still impact MacOS though.